# No confirmation after resubmitting a paper which got "Revision Required"

Tags: publications, peer-review, springer

My paper submitted to a Springer journal got "Revision Required" and a comment on what type of revision was required. I completed that required revision and I want to re-submit the revised paper. On the journal's site there are options for file uploads. I uploaded all files and pressed complete. I didn’t got any submission mail nor any other confirmation. I see there is a file attached after login. I also attached a file to the “Add Discussion“ section.

Comment: Just ask the journal.

Comment: It takes same amount of time to contact the journal as it does posting here. But the journal will know the answer. Don't be shy!

Comment: Thank you.......

Comment: @user2705196 yes sir your were correct after 2 days status changed .